# Exponential power distribution vs Generalized normal distribution

Tags: density-function

[statisticshowto](https://www.statisticshowto.com/exponential-power-distribution/) and many other sources state that the exponential power distribution and the generalized normal distribution are the same.
However, their pdf really look different:
$$
f_{ep} = (e^{1-e^{\lambda x^k}}) e^{\lambda x^k}  \lambda k x^{k-1}
$$
$$
f_{gn} = \frac{\beta}{2 \alpha \Gamma(1/\beta)} e^{-{(\frac{|x-\mu|}{a})}^\beta}
$$
and I couldn't find a way to map them.
Are these two really the same and if yes, how can derive $f_{ep}$ from $f_{gn}$ with some reparametrization ?

Comment: There are many ways to "generalise" a Normal distribution and "statisticshowto and many other sources" may not be that reliable. Note that $f_{ep}$ depends on two parameters, while $f_{gn}$ depends on three. I deem it quite unlikely that a *parameter-free transform * can turn one variate distributed from $f_{ep}$  into a variate distributed from $f_{gn}$

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution#Symmetric_version) is another such source. I fear that there might be a misunderstanding here with the terminologies. Scipy also has two different functions for them [`scipy.stats.exponpow`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.exponpow.html#scipy.stats.exponpow) and [`scipy.stats.gennorm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gennorm.html) without any seemingly relationship. It would be nice if someone can firmly state how they are related.